# Adding HTML Pages into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Within my website that I am converting over into a WordPress CMS theme, there are 7 menu options that go to individual html pages.

My question is, what is the best way to get these 7 html pages into my WordPress CMS theme, i.e. is there a backend means or do I directly add these individual pages as the WordPress Admin?

I've currently got my menu options setup as follows:

```
<li><a href="index.html" class="topm currentMenu nosub">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about-us.html" class="topm nosub">About Us</a></li>
```

Also, how do I link my menu to my pages as well in WordPress?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
You can convert your html pages to wordpress pages by using template pages for your 
each menus.Before that create files name header.php,index.php,sidebar.php,footer.php
,style.css in your theme folder.Then follow the below steps:

1. Include all the contents of your home.html upto your menu creation like this in your 
   header.php:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Course</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="w1">
        <div class="w2">
            <!-- header -->
            <header id="header">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <!-- logo -->
                <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">Company Logo</a></h1>
                <!-- main nav -->
                <nav id="nav">
                <!--**replace your menu listings by the given below codes**-->
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
                </nav>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </header>   
<?php wp_head(); ?>

2. In index.php, include the body contents of home.html
   in between the below codes:


<?php

/**

* Template Name: home
*

* Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.

*/

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

//body contents of home page

<?php get_footer(); ?>

3.Likewise, you can include as much menu you want.Just by changing like this for about 
  us:

<?php

/**

* Template Name: aboutus
*

* Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.

*/

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

//body contents of aboutus page

<?php get_footer(); ?>



4. If you have any footer contents(contents needed to display at the bottom of all 
  pages).Then include the contents in footer.php.If no contents is there,then 
  also simply create a file named footer.php.

5. Include the side contents to sidebar.php(contents to be displayed in right side of 
   the page).If no side contents are there.Then,simply create sidebar.php.

5. style.css,containing the css for all pages.

6.After creating all html files to .php files.Open the admin dashboard of your website.
  In that open,Pages->Add new.In Add New Page,Enter the menu name(Home) in title and in 
  right side,click the Template dropdown and select the template name(home) and click 
  Publish button.

7.Likewise,create pages for all menus by giving title and selecting template name from 
  the template dropdown and click publish button after selecting.

8.Then,open Appearance->Menus.Then Menus page will open,in that on left side corner,you
  will see Pages tag,click view all and check all the pages you want to display as 
  menus in your website and click Add to Menu button.

9.Then,the selected pages will be shown on right side,in bottom you will see Save Menu 
  button,click it.

8.After finishing all,on top left corner click on the website name and see the website 
  with the following menus and their corresponding pages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Clarify your question. Do you want to be able to edit those html pages in WordPress admin? You can't. Pages have to be part of the WP backend and reside in the database to be editable in the editor.

If you just want those pages to be linked in the menus of the WP pages, they must be hardcoded in the header.php (or other page templates) as links, as static html pages can't be called by wp_list_pages or other WP php functions.

Comment: Hi @songdogtech, I deinitely would like my pages to be editable by the end user, i.e. text, add/remove images etc. Would really appreciate the best way to do this or pls point me to a website that demonstrates this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi again @songdogtech - I am somewhat confused with your comment about "Pages have to be part of the WP backend and reside in the database to be editable in the editor." So I understand, are you saying that I just can't take a about-us.html page source, that I have created in Dreamweaver, go into WP-Admin, Pages, Add New Page and drop the html code into the html tab within the <code></code> tags, which might also include images for me to update again later on? If not, how else can I do it as these pages will not be STATIC pages? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "...take a about-us.html page source, that
>   I have created in Dreamweaver, go into
>   WP-Admin, Pages, Add New Page and drop
>   the html code into the html tab within
>   the  tags..."

You ***can*** do that.  But do not use the <code></code> tags (or the page will display your "raw" html.)

It should go something like this:

- Create a new page, title "About".
- Copy and paste the source code that is inside the **<body></body>** tag of your original "about.html" into the html editor (make sure you are in "html" mode -- not "Visual".)

(**NOTE:  <script>** tags (and some other tags) will be stripped by WP when you submit the page.)

- Your "menu options" (I assume this is your navigation?) can't point to "about.html" for this to work as a dynamic, WP-controlled page.  Your new "About" page will likely appear in the navigation, anyway.